# .NET Cache: maximum number of elements

Tags: .net, caching

Is there a maximum number of keys/elements you can have in the .NET Cache? If yes, what is the limit? I am not referring to the maximum size of the Cache in MB.

Comment: Do you mean the `System.Web.Caching.Cache`? If so, it depends on   [`EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.effectivepercentagephysicalmemorylimit.aspx) and `EffectivePrivateBytesLimit`. Otherwise it depends on your memory. As with every collection you can add items until you get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: There is `web cache`, there is `Enterprise Library caching`, which is now part of `Runtime Caching`, there is `AppFabric Cache`. But seriously, none of them have limit on number of items, only amount of memory can throw them off. And some of them can actually detect when they run out of memory and start to unload themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There can't be an accurate limit in bytes as their implementation CAN NOT KNOW how many bytes an object takes (it is possible to figure out, but not available out-of-box). There is no built-in function like "sezeofobject(reference)" because it is impossible to say where the "object ends". Say you have an object that points to 3 other objects, should they be counted as the part of original object?

At any rate, although it is possible to indirectly asses how much ram a caching solution would take, it is not possible to do accurately, for example, one may just use reflection to compute the number of fields and use sizeof() of primitive types, etc.. but again, this will give a ballpark number.

How we solved this problem - we serialize objects that we keep in byte[] - this kills many rabbits with one bullet:

- The object returned from cache is "invisible" to GC and does not
  put any memory pressure on graph traversal
- We can know EXACTLY how many bytes an object graph takes
- The object returned from cache is 100% thread-safe copy

The biggest problem is GC.

The cache classes supplied with .NET are handy, but have a major problem - they can not store much data (tens of millions+) of objects for a long time without killing your GC. They work great if you cache a few thousand objects, but the moment you move into millions and keep them around until they propagate into GEN2 - the GC pauses would eventually start to be noticeable when you system comes to low memory threshold and GC needs to sweep all gens.

The practicality is this - if you need to store a few hundred thousand instances - use MS cache. Does not matter if your objects are 2-field or 25 field - its about the number of references.

On the other hand there are cases when large RAMs, which are common these days, need to be utilized, i.e. 64 GB. For that we have created a 100% managed memory manager and cache that sits on top of it.

Our solution can easily store 300,000,000 object in-memory in-process without taxing GC at all - this is because we store data in large (250 mb) byte[] segments.

Here is the code: NFX Pile (Apache 2.0)
https://github.com/aumcode/nfx/blob/master/Source/NFX/ApplicationModel/Pile/ICache.cs

And video: NFX Pile Cache - Youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dz_7hukyejQ